# Amend Image SRC and Append to Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap, src

** Update, still trying to figure this out but struggling. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. **

I have a HREF that contains an image:

```
<a href="#" class="small-gallery">
    <img src="001.jpg">
</a>
```

On clicking this image, a popup modal (Bootstrap) appears, and fills the modal body (ie. the content of the modal) with the same image as appears inside the HREF. ie:

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this).parents('.small-gallery').html()).appendTo('.modal-body');
  $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
```

This all works great, but what I actually want to do is change the image SRC that appears in modal body, so that it takes the SRC from the image (ie. 001.jpg) and adds a string of "-m" before the image extension, so it changes the image SRC to "001-m.jpg"

So the sequence of events would be:

- Click .small-gallery href
- Grab image SRC from .small-gallery img
- Output full image tag in .modal-body but ensure the image SRC has "-m" before the .jpg extension

I'm sure it's simple, but I'm having a mind dump and can't get it working.

Thanks for your help in advance, and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with help from another forum...

Rather than split the string, supply the new source in a data attribute and grab that instead.

e.g.

```
<a href="#" class="small-gallery">
    <img data-img-modal="001-m.jpg" class="thumbnail" src="001.jpg">
</a>
```

JS

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var myClone = $(this).closest('.small-gallery').clone();
  var theImg =  myClone.find('img');
  var newSrc = $(this).data('img-modal'); 
  theImg.removeClass('thumbnail').attr("src", newSrc);
  myClone.appendTo('.modal-body');
 $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
```